# symfony 3 subquery with join

Tags: symfony, join, querybuilder

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('project')
        ->select('
            project.id, 
            project.name, 
            project.price,
            project.cost,
            project_company.name as company')
        ->addSelect("SUM(project_transactions.sum) AS spent")
        ->leftJoin('project.company', 'project_company')
        ->leftJoin('project.transactions', 'project_transactions')
        ->groupBy('project.id')
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

Это рабочий запрос.
К select этого запроса мне мне нужно добавить следующее:
колонку value из таблицы payment_types которая связана с transactions по полю payment_type_id
Получается мне нужно сделать еще один join на подзапрос, который уже сам по себе является join. 
Как это реализовать?

```
manyToOne:
      paymentType:
          targetEntity: PaymentType
          inversedBy: transactions
          joinColumn:
              name: payment_type_id
              referencedColumnName: id
```

это связь таблицы transactions c таблицей payment_types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решается это просто. В моем случае

```
->leftJoin('project_transactions.paymentType', 'transactions_paymentType')
```